# Azure Website with OrchardCMS causes of Http5xx errors

Tags: c#, azure, orchardcms

I use OrchardCMS 1.8.1 and some time ago the error reports have been arriving.
I haven't made any changes in the code or Azure Website settings, so don't understand what to fix.

That's what I see in the log:

```
    2014-11-10 15:10:18,345 [47] NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction - (null) - Begin transaction failed
 (null)
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException (0x80004005): There is a file sharing violation. A different process might be using the file. [ D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\Sites\Default\Orchard.sdf ]
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.ProcessResults(Int32 hr)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.Open(Boolean silent)
   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.Open()
   at NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider.GetConnection() in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Connection\DriverConnectionProvider.cs:line 46
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.ConnectionManager.GetConnection() in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\AdoNet\ConnectionManager.cs:line 196
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.get_Connection() in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Impl\SessionImpl.cs:line 1634
   at NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Begin(IsolationLevel isolationLevel) in c:\Users\sebros\Documents\My Projects\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Transaction\AdoTransaction.cs:line 137
```

Any idea how to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

You might have had too many concurrent write access on the SqlCe database, which is not adapted for that. I could exclude another process like an antivirus holding the file open as you are mentioning it's on Azure Websites.

Try to restart the service, and ensure the output cache is enabled. Ultimately use Sql Server which can handle high concurrency scenarios better.

Comment: Yep, don't use SqlCE in a production environment. It's good for development, not so robust in prod.

Comment: Yes, you're right SQL Server would solve the problem but MS Azure offers it as is from Box so I hoped those features were considered. In addition, the SQL Server for Website service isn't included to the package and should be ordered additionally so it makes using Azure Website service reasonless